# Visual Studio 2015 error: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-target-select remote :5039". Remote connection closed

Tags: gdb, cross-platform, emulation, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

I see the following error whenever I try to debug "Cross Platform" under "C++" category: **"Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-target-select remote :5039". Remote connection closed"**

I've installed all of the contents when I downloaded Visual Studio 2015 community and I ran it on Windows 10 Pro which supports Hyper-V.

**I've been searching a solution for this and I've found an assumption:**
 "What is your debug target, the VS Android Emulator?  When we saw this before it turned out to be a bad emulator image.  Do you have this problem with all targets (e.g. if you try a physical device) or just one?"
**In my case, I just tried this via Emulator(VS Emulator 5" Lolipop (5.0) XXHDP Phone (0x86 -...)**

**So I've sent an Email to VS 2015.
And the answer was like this:**
 "Sorry for the delay in responding we were looking at an emulator image of another user that ran into this problem so I was waiting until we had the results of that investigation to report back.  We actually were not able to find anything wrong the emulator itself, our current hypothesis is that it is a network or adb problem interfering with GDB’s ability to connect to GDB server on the remote machine.  Do you see this error every time you try to debug, or if you reboot the emulator will it work sometimes right after the reboot?  Next time you see the error, can you open the emulator’s console mode by going go the Hyper-V manager and double clicking the emulator.  Then find the location your app installed to and run “gdbserver --version" from the app path and let me know what it says?  This will validate if the correct version of gdbserver is on the device."

**So we are trying to solve this problem but I'm also asking here just in case.
Is there anyone who has magical solution for this problem?
I'll put a comment on this if I figure out how to solve this.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: PS. Actually I couldn't find the way how to see the location my app installed when I opened the emulator's consol mode. So I just asked again to get more details to follow up the direction I've got.
I'll comment on this whenever I get any improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ** Following answer is from the manager of Visual Studio 2015:

You are only the second person who has run into this issue, and the first person that ran into it provided their everything works correctly when we run their .vhd on our machines so it appears to be some strange problem where gdbserver (which comes from the Android NDK provided by Google) crashes only when running on certain machines. Unfortunately the .vhd you provided does not appear to be the correct one it won’t boot for me.  You can see the .vhd file being used by the emulator if you look under the settings of the emulator in your Hyper-V manager.  .However given we got the other person’s .vhd you can hold off providing any additional information at this point.  I’m waiting to hear back from the emulator team on if they have any ideas since this appears to be an issue only on specific machines since.

If you don’t mind my asking, if you don’t have a background in computers what inspired you to try C++ on Android?  That scenario will be significantly more complicated than doing Java on Android.

---

**It's been almost two months since I got this answer but I haven't got any additional response from them yet. So, I ended up quitting developing an application by using VS2015.**

**If you run into this problem, there are only two ways to go. Change your computer or stop developing application via VS2015.**

Answer (score 0):

If the project name contains spaces, the whole remote debugging fails. Visual Studio also creates weird paths. When checking out the "Blink1 for Raspberry Pi" template, I named the Project "Blink1 for Pi", which resulted in a path like this:

```
~/projects/Blink1?/for/pi/PI/for/pi....
```

And all the debugging failed. When I recreated this keeping the project name "Blink1", everything worked fine. It's a pity, that spaces aren't handled here...